# HPLIP package is broken on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, maverick

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, and when I try to run the Update Manager, it keeps failing when attempting to install the updated `hplip` package. If I run it from the command-line, it shows a Python syntax error and fails after that.

The syntax looks correct in the error returned, so I'm not sure why it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They switched to Python3 in Maverick, but the `hplip` configuration scripts rely on Python2. Change `/usr/bin/python` to point to `/usr/bin/python2.6` instead of `python3.1`.

I hope my searching helps someone else :)